# How to show that a sequence does not converge if it is not bounded above

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that this sequence $\{a_n\}$ = (2n+1)/(3n+5) does not converge to $42$ if it is not bounded above. I have already showed that it converges to $2/3$. For this I want to use a proof by contradiction,i.e, I assume that the sequence does converge to $42$, which will lead to a contradiction to the initial assumption that is the sequence will be bounded above. Any ideas or theorems that can help me solve this question?

Comment: If you've already shown it converges to $\frac{2}{3}$, assuming it converges to $42$ should yield a contradiction very quickly...

Comment: Yes, but I'm finding the solution quite tedious. Is there another efficient approach to this problem?

Comment: You've posted the same question twice. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495784/proof-to-sequences-in-real-analysis ... And you've made a total hash of it the second time. Please do not repost.

Comment: Well, sorry. I didn't know if it is such a big deal.

Comment: @mespebjidom: You might want to take a look at [this question and its answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/473).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will show that there is an $\epsilon\gt 0$ such that 
$$\left|\frac{2n+1}{3n+5}-42\right|\gt \epsilon$$
for infinitely many $n$.

Pick $\epsilon=1$. It is obvious that for positive $n$, we have $\frac{2n+1}{3n+5}\lt 1$. It follows that for all positive $n$, we have $\left|\frac{2n+1}{3n+5}-42\right|\gt 41\gt  \epsilon$.

Comment: So is the unboundedness part redundant? I thought that I could use proof by contradiction by showing that if the sequence converges to 42, then there's a contradiction in the initial assumption of the sequence not being bounded above.

Comment: You had removed that part by the time I answered, which is a good thing, since it was not useful. The sequence is bounded above, but that does not show it doesn't have limit $42$. We can use the fact it is bounded above by $1$, as I did in a formal $\epsilon$-$N$ proof. With the right theorems, you can bypass all this stuff. For example, if you have the theorem that a limit, if it exists, is unique, then you can immediately conclude from your previous work that the limit is not $42$.

Comment: The expression $\frac{2n+1}{3n+5}$ is less than $1$ for any positive $n$, since the top $2n+1$ is less than the bottom $3n+5$. The choice of $\epsilon=1$ has nothing to do with the size of $(2n+1)/(3n+5)$. If it confused you, let $\epsilon=1/7$. In the formal definition of $\lim a_n=a$, we say that whatever positive $\epsilon$ we pick, after a while $|a_n-a|$ is guaranteed to be $\lt \epsilon$. To prove the limit is **not** $42$, we pick a convenient $\epsilon$ (I used $1$, you can use $1/13$ if you like) and show that however far out we go, (Cont)

Comment: (Cont) there will be some $a_n$ whose distance from $42$ is greater than $\epsilon$. In our case, that's easy, for $a_n\lt 1$, so it is always quite far from $42$.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out and actually was silly of me to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems distinctly strange.  For one thing, if the sequence converged to $42$, then it *would* be bounded above!

On the other hand, you have a specific sequence that you already know is converging to $\frac{2}{3}$, so assuming that it converges to something else is simply contradictory (I assume you know that limits are unique).

Let's back up several steps.  Try to show that a convergent sequence is bounded above: that's logically equivalent to your title question and less convoluted.  Can you do that?

Comment: Check out my previous post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495784/proof-to-sequences-in-real-analysis

Comment: @mespebjidom: OK, it seems that much of the strangeness is coming from the question and not from you.  Still my recommendation remains the same: show that a convergent sequence is bounded above.  Do you know how to show this?  Do you agree that it would answer the question?  If so, we're good, and it's certainly a better moral to take away than something about "convergence to 42"...

Comment: Yeah I think should've asked: "If the sequence is not bounded, then how can I prove that it does not converge to 42?"

Comment: @mespebjidom: you could have asked that, but it's logically equivalent to ask "Show that a sequence which converges to $42$ must be bounded," which we can immediately touch up to "Show that a sequence which is convergent must be bounded".  That last statement sounds like a useful fact and not a curiosity.  Again, let me know if you want help on how to show that.

Comment: There's a theorem in my book that says that "If a sequence {an} converges, then {an} is bounded both above and below.". So in a nutshell, that's all I had to apply.

Comment: However, I was wondering that if boundedness is not a sufficient condition for a sequence to converge, then can we directly show that a sequence does not converge regardless of the boundedness/unboundedness assumption?

Comment: @mespebjidom: Your first comment sounds very reasonable.  As for your second: yes, boundedness is necessary but not sufficient for convergence.  If you already know that your sequence converges to $L$, then it's easy to see that it cannot also converge to any $M \neq L$.  In general, if you have a bounded sequence then it can be hard to tell whether it converges (to anything) or not.  This is what the Cauchy criterion, the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, and so forth are about...